# Inline block when creating a struct

Tags: objective-c, block, objective-c-blocks, inline-functions

This is for learning =)
I understand functions, methods and blocks can all be declared and then called. I'm just trying to understand blocks better.

This is a basic idea of what I want to do.

```
CGRectMake(100,^CGFloat(){return 1.0f;},100,100);
```

The compiler is not seeing the return value of the block and is instead seeing the block itself as the value which results in an error. I tried a few ways of casting the block but was unable to figure out a solution.

Is there a way to do this and if so how? If not is there another way to do an inline function with a return value?

**Edit**
Heres a code example I'm using based on the correct answers first example.

```
valueLabelMin.frame = CGRectMake(0,
                                 ^CGFloat(){
                                   if (CGRectGetMaxY(dateRangeStartLabel.frame)) {
                                     return CGRectGetMaxY(dateRangeStartLabel.frame)-20;
                                   }else{
                                     return self.bounds.size.height-20;
                                   }
                                 }(),
                                 50,
                                 20);
```

**Edit 2** This goes a little out of the context of the original question but demonstrates its relevance in a context which I always appreciate when reading questions.

This example code changes the frame of some UILabels based on conditions, is optionally animated and executes a completion block.

Notice that each labels setFrame is called only once resulting in very manageable code =D
Needles to say, the "before" version was such a mess I can't bring myself to include it.

```
- (void)updateValueRangeLabels:(BOOL)animated completion:(void(^)(void))completion {

    void (^setLabelFrames)() = ^()
    {
        valueLabelMax.frame = CGRectMake(^CGFloat(){if(_showValueRange){return 0;}else{return -50;}}(),
                                         CGRectGetMaxY(titleLabel.frame),
                                         50, 20);

        valueLabelMid.frame = CGRectMake(^CGFloat(){if(_showValueRange){return 0;}else{return -50;}}(),
                                         CGRectGetMaxY(titleLabel.frame) + (self.bounds.size.height - CGRectGetMaxY(titleLabel.frame) - CGRectGetMinY(dateRangeStartLabel.frame) - 20)/2,
                                         50, 20);

        valueLabelMin.frame = CGRectMake(^CGFloat(){if(_showValueRange){return 0;}else{return -50;}}(),
                                         ^CGFloat(){if(_showDateRange){return CGRectGetMinY(dateRangeStartLabel.frame)-20;}else{return self.bounds.size.height - 20;}}(),
                                         50, 20);
    };

    if (animated) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
            setLabelFrames();
        }completion:^(BOOL finished){
            completion();
        }];
    }else{
        setLabelFrames();
        completion();
    }
}
```

Blocks are amazing!

Comment: you know there's such a syntax as `_showValueRange ? 0 : -50`, right?

Comment: I didn't when I had this question no, but I've since learned about it and use it frequently now. Blocks still rock though :D

For anyone that doesn't know, _showValueRange ? 0 : -50
is the same as
float value;
if (_showValueRange == YES) {
 value = 0;
}else{
 value = -50;
}

It's
(evaluate)?returnTrue:returnFalse
and can be used inline. You can even child them together like this:
(evaluate)?returnTrue:(evaluate)?returnTrue:returnFalse;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Evaluate it, like so:

```
CGRect r = CGRectMake(100,^CGFloat(){return 1.0f;}(),100,100);
                                                  ^^
```

Another example, introducing a parameter:

```
// creates a CGRect with all values set to the parameter (12 in this example)
CGRect r = ^CGRect(CGFloat p){return (CGRect){p,p,p,p};}(12);
```

Comment: Great! I've never seen that syntax before though. Just tried `1.0f()` and the compiler gave me a clue. I'm guessing thats inherited from c like a function. Maybe it's making the block a c function? I feel like a whole bunch of doors just opened! Yay fundamentals!

Comment: Second example blew my mind... Usually setting the frame requires multiple conditionals for me so I end up with a string of `if` `else` statements all containing a setFrame. So cool... Blocks are great =P

Comment: @STREGA'sGate yep, calling is like C. a block is a basic function *object*. it is like a C function pointer but more complex because it is also able to capture and refer to other variables (e.g. `CGFloat x = 34.0f; \n CGFloat (^b)() = ^CGFloat() {return x;};` ). that is convenient because the problem in C with passing function objects and `void*` via context info was a big pitfall and restriction (at times). so the context adds a lot of flexibility and type safety. the block is evaluated when it is called. it's also nice that they can perform ref counting of captured objc objects.

Answer (score 0):

**Plain**

```
CGRect frame = view.frame;
frame.origin.x = 12;
view.frame = frame:
```

**Parantheses**

```
view.frame = (CGRect frame = view.frame; frame.origin.x = 12; frame);
```

**Block**

```
view.frame = ^{CGRect frame = view.frame; frame.origin.x = 12; return frame; }();
```